# How to preserve nested array value when modify a value of an cloned array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a default nested array called `default_array`, very simple :

```
default_array = [
        ["a", "b", "c"] 
];
```

And I create a obj called `obj` where the value of his `array` attribute is the copy of `default_array` :

```
obj = {

    "array" : default_array.slice(0)
};
```

But when I modify a element of the `obj.array` like this :

```
obj.array[0][0] = "z";
```

This modify also the `default_array`. I want this modification doesn't affect  `default_array`. I want to preserve `default_array`.

Any idea ?

Comment: Try `var copy = default_array.map(function(e) { return e; });` Then use `copy`

Comment: .map not supported by IE8.

Comment: Use [Pollyfill from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Polyfill). This should be added in Question, IE8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function copy(array) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; i++) {
        result.push(array[i].slice());
    }
    return result;
}

var default_array = [
    ["a", "b", "c"]
];
var obj = {
    "array": copy(default_array)
};

obj.array[0][0] = 'z';
console.log(obj.array);
console.log(default_array);
```

Comment: Extended version for case if in parent array not only arrays https://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/o96hL8L9/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try using `map` or Or you can use combination of `JSON.parse` & `JSON.stringify` since you are having a nested/multidimensional array:

```
default_array = [
    ["a", "b", "c"]
];
var newArray = default_array.map(function(arr) {
    return arr.slice();
});
//Or you can use combination of JSON.parse & Stringify
var newArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(default_array));
obj = {
    "array": newArray.slice(0)
};
```

Comment: map not supported by IE8. Without .map() and without jquery is possible ?

Comment: you can use combination of `JSON.parse` & `JSON.stringify` see edit

Comment: Nit: This will not work if all the elements of `default_array` are not arrays.

Answer (score 0):

This may be overkill for your problem, but if you are running into it more and more, consider using Immutable.js

It provides efficient immutable datatypes.... just look at https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/ for example code that uses the ibrary.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
obj = {
    "array" : JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(default_array))
};
```